# Spelling error in suggested edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, spelling

> You have voted to approve this edit - awaiting more votse.

That is all.

[image: Trifecta]

Freehand circle, within a freehand circle. WITH A FREEHAND ARROW!

Comment: I suppose I ought to make the obligatory "screen shot (with free hand circles) or it didn't happen" comment here.

Comment: Thy will be done.

Comment: The red freehand circle has a hole in it at the top which will make that man inside it quite cold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the quote you posted appears to have a spelling mistake in it.  This can be amended by switching the `'s'` character with the `'e'` character in the offending word .

See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/votes for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply, I will conciser accepting this answer in a short while. Yours, Ólafur Waage

Comment: Thank you for you comment and acknowledgement.

Comment: um, wtf? [.](http://google.com)

Answer (score 13):

Thank you for your error report. Your freehand circles were extremely helpful for us in reproducing this.

[Tom Gullen's suggested bug fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79485/spelling-error-in-suggested-edits/79502#79502) has been considered. However, applying it directly as-is would have required an intellectual property signover. So instead of switching `e` and `s`, we decided to instead remove both characters, and then re-add them in the correct order.

Yet we do acknowledge that our solution to this problem is strongly inspired by Tom's work, so I ask everyone to cast votse of appreciation on his answer.

The fix will be available as soon as we deploy. Our security experts have audited the bug and given it an exploitabilty risk assessment score of π%, which – according to our standard process manual – is below the threshold requiring an immediate rebuilt; hence it may be a while until the correct message is published.

Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for addressing this within a frame of time that fairly represents the urgency of the bug.  One thing that concerns me though is how can we be sure that we won't see this sort of bug again?  I'll be honest, I found the bugs existence to be quite distressing.

Comment: @Tom Yes[.](http://example.com)

Comment: Awesome. {15 chars}

Comment: I find it intriguing that you would go to the trouble of adding a dummy link when you could have just addressed @Tom Gullen by his full name instead.

Comment: @mmyers: I wanted to have the comedic effect of a very short answer to a very long question. Believe me, this is all part of my big master plan.